# $K^{ur}K^{\pi} = L$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-fields

Let $K$ be a $p$-adic field, and $L$ an infinite abelian extension of $K$ containing $K^{ur}$.  Let $\Phi: K^{\ast} \rightarrow Gal(L/K)$ be the local Artin map.  Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer for $K$, and $K^{\pi}$ the fixed field of the subgroup of $Gal(L/K)$ generated by $\Phi(\pi)$.  Is there an elementary way (say, without cohomology) of seeing that $L = K^{ur} K^{\pi}$?